# XSL, XML table shows but does not populate w/ text

Tags: xml, xslt

Ok, I'm new to XML and XSL.  Ultimately I want to populate this table with filters based on user input but thought I'd start with the whole table.

Here's a portion of my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="XSLstylesheet.xsl"?>
<data-set>
<rep>
    <RepID>12345</RepID>
    <Rep>SomeName</Rep>
    <Dept>PS</Dept>
    <Station>1</Station>
    <ClassDate>41593</ClassDate>
    <Agency>AGency</Agency>
    <EmAppr>y</EmAppr>
</rep>
<rep>
    <RepID>98765</RepID>
    <Rep>Another Name</Rep>
    <Dept>HC</Dept>
    <Station>2</Station>
    <ClassDate>41593</ClassDate>
    <Agency>Next Agency</Agency>
    <EmAppr>y</EmAppr>
</rep>
...

</rep>
</data-set>
```

So here's my XSL:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
      <h2>Representatives</h2>
        <table border="1">
          <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
              <th>Rep</th>
              <th>Rep ID</th>
              <th>Department</th>
              <th>Station</th>
              <th>Start Date</th>
              <th>Agency</th>
              <th>Out of Approval Queue</th>
          </tr>
     <xsl:for-each select="data-set/rep">
           <tr>
                  <td><xsl:value-of select="data-set/Rep"/></td>
                  <td><xsl:value-of select="data-set/RepID"/></td>
                  <td><xsl:value-of select="data-set/Dept"/></td>
                  <td><xsl:value-of select="data-set/Station"/></td>
                  <td><xsl:value-of select="data-set/ClassDate"/></td>
                  <td><xsl:value-of select="data-set/Agency"/></td>
                  <td><xsl:value-of select="data-set/EmAppr"/></td>
                </tr>
                </xsl:for-each>
              </table>
              </body>
              </html>
            </xsl:template>

            </xsl:stylesheet>
```

When I view it, the table shows up with the right number of rows and columns but there's absolutely no text.  It's like it recognizes the record but isn't populating it.  Where did I go wrong?  I'm tearing my hair out.

Comment: Please mark the answer below as the "Accepted Answer" if it helped!

Answer (score 3):

Your xpath is wrong. Change from

```
<td><xsl:value-of select="data-set/Rep"/></td>
```

to

```
<td><xsl:value-of select="Rep"/></td>
```

You are already visiting the nodes `data-set/rep`, so you dont need to add `data-set` again. Your current code is visiting each node at `data-set/data-set/rep`, which looks like a typo.

Do this for all your for-each statements in the example

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <h2>Representatives</h2>
                <table border="1">
                    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                        <th>Rep</th>
                        <th>Rep ID</th>
                        <th>Department</th>
                        <th>Station</th>
                        <th>Start Date</th>
                        <th>Agency</th>
                        <th>Out of Approval Queue</th>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="data-set/rep">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="Rep"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="RepID"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="Dept"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="Station"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="ClassDate"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="Agency"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="EmAppr"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```